# How to get full selection from Excel sheet using VBA without the filtered rows that are in between

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a selection from a worksheet in Excel using VBA, to use this selection as input for a next step of analysis on the data.
This works fine, until you make a selection that has filtered rows in between. In that case it will only get the part of the range that is before the filtered rows.

How can I also get the selected row(s) after the filtered rows?

Below is the code that I use for getting the selected rows from the sheet, and an example of a selection where the code does not work as intended.

```
    For Each area In Selection.Areas
        Set newRange = area
        Set rnge = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For i = 1 To rnge.Rows.Count
            x = rnge.Cells(i, 5).Value
            y = rnge.Cells(i, 6).Value
            Write #1, x, y
        Next i
    Next
```

[image]

Update: using the code below, I got it to work, thanks to SNicolaou's answer

```
    Set rnge = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each area In rnge.Areas
        For i = 1 To area.Rows.Count
            x = area.Cells(i, 5).Value
            y = area.Cells(i, 6).Value
            Write #1, x, y
        Next i
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to how to select the cells:
for example, holding the shift key and clicking individually on two cells then you have two areas in your selection. holding the shift key and click and drag to select the two cells will create one area. ie. if my cells are A1 and B1 then in the first case i will get two areas "$A$1","$B$1" whereas in the second case you will get one area "$A$1:$B$1"

So if you want to go for one selection then you will need to split the selection as below:

```
Private Sub sTestSolution()

  Dim area As Range, newRange As Range
  Dim i As Long, x As Variant, y As Variant

  Set newRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  For Each area In newRange.Areas
    Debug.Print area.Address
  Next

End Sub
```

If you want to go for multiple selection then the code will be like this (adjust accordingly):

```
Private Sub sTestSolution()

  Dim area As Range
  Dim i As Long, x As Variant, y As Variant

  For Each area In Selection.Areas
      For i = 1 To area.Rows.Count
          x = area.Cells(i, 1).Value
          y = area.Cells(i, 2).Value
          Debug.Print area.Address
      Next i
    Next

End Sub
```

Following up on your comment, i get the below when i have selected those rows in my screenshot.
[image]

Comment: ideally, you want a combination of the two so you don't worry how you select your cells/rows.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but it is not a solution to my problem. The problem is that when I select 2 rows next to eachother (so 1 area), it will in this specific case not have the second row in the area.

Comment: See my updated post. Plus, going back to the code you have posted, there is definitely something wrong how you set your range variables, do revisit it i.e. "Set rnge = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" will always give you the same rnge, why is it in the loop???

Comment: You are right. I overlooked the fact that I used Selection here instead of the area. I cleaned up the code and checked if I used correct parameters inside the loop, and it is working now. Thanks for the help, and I will update my original post with the solution, which is a combination of your separate solutions.