# How to exclude hidden cells in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a loop to read text values of cells in a specific column (D) in a range. Some rows are filtered. I don't want to include filtered cells in the loop.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To VisibleCellsCount
    Workbooks("Samples").Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(i + 1)
    Worksheets(i + 2).Activate
    CommunityName = Workbooks("Sampling Template_New").Sheets("Samples").Range("D" & FirstRow + i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value
    Workbooks("Samples").Sheets(i + 2).Name = CommunityName
Next I
```

I need the string variable to get only the visible cells' values.

Comment: I tried this, but it wouldn't work in a one column range.

Comment: Are you using a loop? There's no loop in the code you've provided.

Comment: [I think this question has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba?rq=1)

Comment: As Alfie said, your loop does not care if cells are visible or not. You have to include an `if statement` to only run the nested code if `EntireRow.Hidden = False`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197316/how-to-get-full-selection-from-excel-sheet-using-vba-without-the-filtered-rows-t

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)

Comment: What is the filename of the workbook the macro is in ?, Is  it "Sampling Template_New" or "Sampling Template_New.xlsm". Can you show the complete sub or at least the part that creates VisibleCellsCount

Comment: Yes, it is 'Sampling Template_New.xlsm'.

Comment: Why do you have Workbooks("Sampling Template_New") in your code if the name is  'Sampling Template_New.xlsm' ? Is this macro in that workbook on a sheet, in a module or in a Personal Workbook ?. Is the other workbook Samples.xlsm open when you run the macro ?